# How to fetch from server on Redux Rehydrate?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm using React/Redux and redux-persist to maintain local storage persistence. I'm looking to load an 'appSettings.json' from the server when redux-persist has finished Rehydrating the store from local storage.

In the persistStore method there is a callback function that is guaranteed to come after the store has been rehydrated, but I then need to make a server call to fetch the appSettings.json.

Is there a way in which I can await the fetch until the server responds?

I require the API URL from the appSettings.json in order to make API calls, but the calls from within the components are occurring before the appSettings fetch has returned.

```
const persistor = persistStore(store, persistConfig, async () => {

return await fetch('settings.json')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        store.dispatch({ type: "API_BASE_RESPONSE",  base_api_url: data.baseApiUrl });
    })

});
```

I've tried a few different variations of awaiting but with no luck. Is there perhaps an even better method of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to resolve (for now) this by adding a method to the PersistGate of redux-persist.

```
const onBeforeLift = async () => {

    // take some action before the gate lifts
    return await fetch('settings.json')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            store.dispatch({ type: "API_BASE_RESPONSE",  base_api_url: data.baseApiUrl });
        })
}

ReactDOM.render((
    // specify basename below if running in a subdirectory or set as "/" if app runs in root
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate 
            onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift}
            persistor={persistor}>
            <BrowserRouter basename={WP_BASE_HREF}>
                <Routes />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>

), document.getElementById('app'))
```